# Comparing one element of an array to multiple elements of another array

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm writing a piece of code for a slot machine project, I have two arrays working.
I would like to compare one element of array 1 with multiple element of array 2.

This is my current piece of code, I took a swing at it but I don't think this is correct.

```
char arrayOne[10]{ 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5 };
char arrayTwo[10]{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

if (arrayTwo[0] == arrayOne[0 - 1])
    cout << "The Numbers are the same";
else
    cout << "the numbers are different";
_getch();
```

Comment: What is making you think that it isn't correct?

Comment: I might have been looking into the wrong place in my code if this is correct then.

Comment: I changed the example to a better one i just made, the output i would like are the numbers are the same, but it comes up with the numbers are different.

Comment: What do you think `0-1` means? If you intended to write a range, that's not how it works, take a look at loops instead.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, the syntax you've written is the same as: `arrayTwo[0] == arrayOne[-1]`, which I'm fairly sure we both agree is not what you want.

You're looking for:

```
((arrayTwo[0] == arrayOne[0]) and (arrayTwo[0] == arrayOne[1]))
```

If you want to match against an arbitrary number of elements, then you should learn about loops:

```
bool truthiness = true;
for (int i=0; i<10; ++i) {
    truthiness = truthiness and (arrayTwo[0] == arrayOne[i]);
}
if (truthiness) {
    cout << "The numbers are the same";
} else {
    cout << "The numbers are different";
}
```

Comment: That is correct =), but if i want to do a range of numbers and not make them negative how would i go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a loop. I've written this small function for you...

```
int
array_range_compare (char *array, int compare_value, int start, int end)
{
    for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        if (compare_value != array[i]) {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return 1;
}
```

This will compare the value of `compare_value` to the values of keys `start` through `end` in `array`. For you `array` is `arrayOne`, `start` is `0`, `end` is `1`, and `compare_value` is `arrayTwo[0]`, all of the variables but `array` are integers.

You can use this function like so...

```
char arrayOne[10] = { 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5 };
char arrayTwo[10] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

if (array_range_compare (arrayOne, arrayTwo[0], 0, 1)) {
    std::cout << "The Numbers are the same";
} else {
    std::cout << "the numbers are different";
}
```